# DocuSign used with Drawloop Document Generation

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to use the DocuSign along with the DrawLoop Document Generation by selecting it as a Delivery Option. I currently have Developer Sandbox Environment. I have the below setting 
[image]

[image]

When I try to generate the Document I am getting the error like

`An invalid URL was specified for use with DocuSign. Please contact your administrator to properly configure DocuSign for document generation. (ResourceInvalid)
Include this Error Id if you contact support: 1ab6a4c5-c0ec-43ae-9a65-5bee4d637c08`

Not sure what I am missing here. Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to contact Drawloop support for the exact format, but the base URL should likely be something like `https://www.docusign.net/restapi` or `https://na3.docusign.net/restapi` depending on what server your DocuSign account is on.

If you're trying to connect to a Demo DocuSign Sandbox, the baseurl may be `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi`